# Problems with SUMPRODUCT

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to use a formula that sums the values in one column, that match a particular criterion across various other columns.

My formula is as follows:
SUMPRODUCT(--(Chart!$AJ$1:$EN$1000=H$2),Chart!$T$1:$T$1000)

However, I get a #VALUE! error.

The T column holds the values to be summed, whereas the criterion is to be found all over the columns AJ:EN.
Whta's the criterion (H$2)? It's "OCTOBER 2020". There are columns within the AJ:EN range that have months. The issue is that there are 15 columns with months (no, they cannot be re-arranged), and instead of using a formula for each of those columns, I wanted to make a single formula to keep things nice and tidy. The other columns have numbers and dates (which is probably why I get the value error).

The funny thing is that if I use a regular SUMIF:
SUMIF(Chart!$AH$1:$EN$1000,H$2,Chart!T1:$T$1000)

I do get a result. The formula works well. However, I need to add other criteria, so I have to use either SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT, yet I get a value error with both, even if I look up for a single criterion.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you separate the arguments in SumProduct() with commas, all the ranges must be the same size.

In order to process a multi column range in the condition and sum up a single column range for the result, you need to multiply the parameters. Like this simplified version of your formula:

wrong approach:  `=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$C$5="a",$D$1:$D$5)`

right approach: `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$C$5="a")*$D$1:$D$5)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting a Value Error. My formula is now like this: SUMPRODUCT((Chart!$AH$1:$EN$1000=H$2)*(Chart!$T$1:$T$1000)), but it's not working.

Comment: You will get tha error if any of the values in T1:T1000 contains text or a space. All values in T1:T1000 must be numeric. You see in my screenshot that the formula works. If it does not work for you, then the problem is with your data, not the formula. Use this formula in a cell in row 1 `=isnumber(T1)`. Copy it down and look for the FALSE result.

Comment: Is your first row of data numeric? Or does the first row have text labels? If the first row has text labels or column headers, you need to start the formula ranges with row 2, not 1. All references must start in row 2.

Comment: Yeah! That did it. I was also adding the headers. Without them the formula works well.

Comment: One last question, is it possible to have multiple columns summed? I mean, right now I'm summing only column T, but what if I wanted to sum all the columns in a range that have a specific header?
I tried this but it didn't work:
SUMPRODUCT((Chart!$AH$2:$EO$1000=H$2)*INDEX(Chart!$AH$2:$EO$1000,,MATCH("* PROFIT *",Chart!$AH$1:$EO$1,0)))

Comment: You cannot nest an Index in a SumProduct. How about you ask a new question for this scenario? It doesn't cost anything and a new question will get more attention.